# Azure Service Fabric Duplex Connection

Tags: wcf, azure, connection, azure-service-fabric, duplex

Is there any way to implement full-duplex connection between the client and Azure Service Fabric stateles service? (WCF is for Ideal case).

I have read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication) but there is nothing about bidirectional communication.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work, Services are normal executables. Read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-wcf) about using WCF in Service Fabric. And [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064(v=vs.110).aspx) about duplex bindings in general.